# Display some lines from file in java

Tags: java, file

I have a txt file that contains 10 lines, and I would like to write Java code to display lines 3 through 5.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Open the file, manually index each line. Read each line and print the indexes you want/need. After doing the job, close the resources.

Comment: Use a simple loop with a counter. This would only for this case though. That's the simplest way.

Comment: `Files.lines(Paths.get("yourFile")).skip(3).limit(2).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @aioobe plz post up your answer with some explanation so I can vote u up thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  void Scan(String filename, int start, int end) {
      Scanner in = null;
      try {
          in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
      } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      int line = 1;
      while(line < start) {
          in.nextLine();
          line++;
      }
      while(line <= end) {
          System.out.println(in.nextLine());
          line++;
      }
  }
```

}